# both signed and unsigned as function parameter

Tags: c++, types

I have functions to read data from an EEPROM. When I want to read a short, regardless of it being signed or unsigned, I know I have to read 2 bytes. Same principle goes when I want to read an integer: I have to read 4 bytes, regardless of it being signed or unsigned.

Thus I wrote 4 functions: one that reads a short, one that reads an unsigned short, one that reads an int, one that reads an unsigned int, etc.

Usage looks like this :

```
// define a default value at zero
uint16_t API_PORT = 0;

// retrieve the API port, that would be between 0 to 65535, saved on the EEPROM
i2cReadUnsignedShortFromExternalEEPROM(I2C_ADDR_EEPROM, 12345, &API_PORT);

// the function
void i2cReadUnsignedShortFromExternalEEPROM(int i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, unsigned int atAdress, uint16_t *number) {
  byte firstByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAdress);
  byte secondByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAdress + 1);

  *number = (firstByte << 8) + secondByte;
}
```

The function to read a SIGNED short is almost exactly the same, except the third parameter :

```
void i2cReadShortFromExternalEEPROM(int i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, unsigned int atAdress, short *number) {
  byte firstByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAdress);
  byte secondByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAdress + 1);

  *number = (firstByte << 8) + secondByte;
}
```

Eventhough everything works fine, it bothers me as it introduces a lot of redundancy in my code.

Is there a way to refactor those two similar functions into just one?
The function would need to work in both following pseudocode scenarios :

```
unsigned short myUnsignedVar = 0;
myNewMethod(I2C_ADDR_EEPROM, 10, &myUnsignedVar);
// myUnsignedVar now holds value of 65000

signed short mySignedVar = 0;
myNewMethod(I2C_ADDR_EEPROM, 12, &mySignedVar);
// mySignedVar now holds value of -123
```

In other words, I want to make it so that the function accepts both signed and unsigned as 3rd parameter.
I'm new to C++

Comment: You could implement the function that reads `unsigned short` by calling the function that reads `short`, then simply casting the result.

Comment: What type is `byte`?

Comment: You can eliminate typed redundancy by using template functions.

Comment: Prefer to use `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, `uint16_t`, `int16_t`, etc.  The standard types, `char`, `short` and `int` are based on ranges, not bit-width.

Comment: Why are you returning your results via output parameters, and not as the return value of the functions?

Comment: @PaulSanders Why not? I agree it would make my life easier if I just returned the value but I often read this is better?

Comment: Where did you read that?  Anyway, it's not true.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot remember. I read it many times on various places (boards/blogs) where people could easily object in the comments/thread but did not, so I took it for granted. It was related to memory, that I am sure of. Feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Passing an out parameter is often recommended for a function that returns a separate error status.   But your code does not do that, so negates any benefits of passing an out parameter over returning the value.    In any event, why not write some generic function with the core logic you seek, and call that from your four functions (with different arguments/values corresponding to particular cases)?

Comment: @Musa It's less efficient, for one thing, and also you can't write things like `std::cout << my_func ();`

Answer (score 1):

Following @Taekahn 's comment regarding function templates, my function now looks like this :

```
template <typename T>
void i2cReadShortFromExternalEEPROM(int i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, unsigned int atAddress, T *number) {
  byte firstByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAddress);
  byte secondByte = i2cReadByteFromExternalEEPROM(i2cAddressOfExternalEEPROM, atAddress + 1);

  *number = (firstByte << 8) + secondByte;
}
```

It seems to work fine (tested).

Example of usage :

```
i2cReadShortFromExternalEEPROM<uint16_t>(I2C_ADDR_EEPROM, some_page, &API_PORT); // 443

i2cReadShortFromExternalEEPROM<short>(I2C_ADDR_EEPROM, some_page, &DEPTH); // -12345
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: You might want to restrict the template so it can only be used for appropriate types.